# What is the code for compressing text in python?

Tags: python, compression

Develop a program that examines a sentence that hasn’t got any punctuation and finds and identifies the positions of each word that occurs in the sentence. With that the system shouldn’t be case sensitive: text, Text, TEXT should be treated as the same word. The program must be able create a list of positions for words in that list and then be able to save the lists as individual files or separate files.

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem yourself by writing some code?

Comment: At best, this sounds like homework and you haven't demonstrated your efforts. At worst, you asking us to do your job. And compression has nothing to do with the body of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that words in the sentence are spaced with ONE space only the following should work:

```
import pickle

words = sentence.lower().split()
pos = 0
result = []
for w in words:
    result.append((w, pos))
    pos += len(w) + 1
with open('filename','w') as o:
    o.write(pickle.dumps(result))
```

Comment: This does not create a list of positions for words present several times in the sentence

Comment: Yeah come on, Dick, write the code for Nicole properly. I'm being ironic. SO isn't advertised as a code-writing service